# Ruby on Rails: cURL DELETE token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to do REST API for the server in RoR which will be used by mobile application.

My project is significantly based on

http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/

and because in the latest versions of DEVISE gem there isn't token authentication, I also use this way:

https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6

**Now occurs my problem - when I'm testing API using cURL, POST (sign in) is correct, but DELETE (logout) not working.** I'm typing in the terminal:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/\?auth_token\=CvX8WZr2MjVhWYxxEXYy
```

or

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions -d "{\"auth_token\":\"CvX8WZr2MjVhWYxxEXYy\"}"
```

(with **my specific token** of course) and I have the answer:

```
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."} with HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

in addition server log:

```
Started DELETE "/api/v1/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-07 03:11:17 +0200
Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#destroy as JSON
  Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"CvX8WZr2MjVhWYxxEXYy", "session"=>{"auth_token"=>"CvX8WZr2MjVhWYxxEXYy"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

My code of the key files:

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    private
    def authenticate_user_from_token!
        user_email = params[:user_email].presence
        user = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

        if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, params[:user_token])
            sign_in user, store: false
        end
    end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  respond_to :json

  def create
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
  end

  def destroy
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    current_user.update_column(:authentication_token, nil)
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged out",
                      :data => {} }
  end

  def failure
    render :status => 401,
           :json => { :success => false,
                      :info => "Login Failed",
                      :data => {} }
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  before_save :ensure_authentication_token

  def ensure_authentication_token
      if authentication_token.blank?
          self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
      end
  end

  def skip_confirmation!
      self.confirmed_at = Time.now
  end

  private

  def generate_authentication_token
      loop do
          token = Devise.friendly_token
          break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
      end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Ihome::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
  devise_for :users

  root 'welcome#index'

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_scope :user do
        post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'login'
        delete 'sessions' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What is incorrectly, because I analyzed the entire program and I cannot find the cause of the error ?

Comment: Have you checked the session exists when you trying to log out? and you sure thats the token related to it? if yes how did you find that out?

Comment: FYI: I'm also seeing something similar: https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication/issues/76   No solution yet, but extremely similar - it looks like it should work, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Same here after logout i am getting error as, Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected..!!! Trying to get it but no luck, Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I referenced this question in a GitHub issue for SimpleTokenAuthentication, a gem that implements the token authentication pattern.  See https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication for more info on the gem.

I initially thought that your issue was the same that I was running into, since I am also getting 401s only on the logout action.  However, @gonzalo-bulnes appears to have spotted your issue.

See https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication/issues/76#issuecomment-46836215

> ...isn't ukson forgetting to provide the user_email param? Token
>   authentication can't be performed with the only auth_token. (In fact,
>   the point of the José Valim's gist is to explain how to perform that
>   [e-mail
>   cross-checking](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6#file-2_safe_token_authentication-rb-L14-L15)
>   when implementing token authentication.)

From my own review of your code, he seems to be right.  Try adding this param and see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be the parameter names you are using to pass in the token value AND the fact that the email value is missing (what shedd contributed).

In the authenticate_entity_from_token! method from the file acts_as_token_authentication_handler.rb there is the following:

params_token_name = "#{entity_class.name.singularize.underscore}_token".to_sym
params_email_name = "#{entity_class.name.singularize.underscore}_email".to_sym

In your case this means that the curl command should be:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/sessions/\?user_token\=CvX8WZr2MjVhWYxxEXYy\&user_email=user@example.com
```